# Insert Registration Data in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, storage, phpmyadmin, normalization

I may not be asking this in the best way possible but i will try my hardest. Thank you ahead of time for your help:

I am creating an enrollment website which allows an individual OR manager to enroll for medical testing services for professional athletes. I will NOT be using the site as a query DB which anybody can view information stored within the database. The information is instead simply stored, and passed along in a CSV format to our network provider so they can use as needed after the fact. There are two possible scenarios:

### Scenario 1 - Individual Enrollment

If an individual athlete chooses to enroll him/herself, they enter their personal information, submit their payment information (credit/bank account) for processing, and their information is stored in an online database as Athlete1.

### Scenario 2 - Manager Enrollment

If a manager chooses to enroll several athletes he manages/ promotes for, he enters his personal information, then enters the personal information for each athlete he wishes to pay for (name, address, ssn, dob, etc), then submits payment information for ALL athletes he is enrolling. This number can range from 1 single athlete, up to 20 athletes per single enrollment (he can return and complete a follow up enrollment for additional athletes).

---

Initially, I was building the database to house ALL information regardless of enrollment type in a single table which housed over 400 columns (think 20 athletes with over 10 fields per athlete such as name, dob, ssn, etc).

Now that I think about it more, I believe create multiple tables (manager(s), athlete(s)) may be a better idea here but still not quite sure how to go about it for the following very important reasons:

### Issue 1

If I list the manager as the parent table, I am afraid the individual enrolling athlete will not show up in the primary table and will not be included in the overall registration file which needs to be sent on to the network providers.

### Issue 2

All athletes being enrolled by a manager are being stored in SESSION as F1FirstName, F2FirstName where F1 and F2 relate to the id of the fighter. I am not sure technically speaking how to store multiple pieces of information within the same table under separate rows using PHP. For example, all athleteswill have a first name. The very basic theory of what i am trying to do is:

If number_of_athletes >1, 
store F1FirstName in row 1, column 1 of Table "Athletes"; 
store F1LastName in row 1, column 2 of Table "Athletes"; 
store F2FirstName in row 2, column 1 of Table "Athletes";
store F2LastName in row 2, column 2 of table "Athletes";

Does this make sense? I know this question is very long and probably difficult so i appreciate the guidance.

Comment: To clarify because I am getting many answers which give me the impression others think I intend to use this data for mining purposes. At the end of the registration all I care about is that one record is inserted and this record shows who did it, the information about them and their subsequents, and how they paid. ALL of that information is then sent in CSV format to the medical testing company who handles the rest from their side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create two tables: `managers` and `athletes`

The `athletes` table would contain a column named `manager_id` which would contain the id of the manager who signed the athlete up or `NULL` if the athlete signed himself up.

During output, create two CSV files (one for each table).

Further reading:

[Defining Relationships](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html#04)

Comment: webbiedave - I think this is probably the best route to go although i do have a question regarding the relationships. Because the manager is signing up at the same time as the athletes, I would likely need to create a unique ID for each manager enrollment. Any ideas how to do this? 

Also, I'm not entirely familiar with how to insert a single registration into multiple tables and multiple rows within a table. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: and thinking about it more - i feel I may need 3 tables - one which details the overall Enrollment Type (individual or group), enrollment date, session ID, etc. Thoughts?

Comment: Is there a possibility that athletes will register before their managers? 

If not then you should have no trouble just using auto-increment to create there ids. 

If there is a possibility that they will then you could probably create a unique ID using a hash of their first and last names, but you would need to make sure that people atleast knew how there names were spelled.

Comment: @noctrine - Athletes could never register before their managers EXCEPT when an individual athlete enrolls himself. This wouldn't matter however because the only reason a manager would enroll a athlete is so that he can pay for that particular athlete. We give managers the option to enroll multiple athletes so they dont have to go through a laborous process several times. 

Ultimately, the 'registration' process needs to be stored in a single table in my mind because that ENTIRE registration is going to be sent along after the fact - we are not looking to store so we can run queries off of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you will retain the names for a future submission, then you should use a different design.  You should also consider if a manager can also be an athlete.  With those points in mind, consider having three tables: PEOPLE, REGISTRATION and REGISTRATION_ATHLETE.  PEOPLE contains all athletes and manager.  REGISTRATION is the Master table that has all the information for a submission of one or more individuals for testing.  REGISTRATION_ATHLETE has one row for every Athlete to be tested.

```
People table:
---------------
People_ID
Type (A for Athlete, M for Manager B for Both)
First Name
Last Name
Birthdate
other columns of value

Registration table:
-------------------
Registration_ID
Registration_Date
People_ID  (person requesting registration - Foreign Key to PEOPLE)
Payment columns....

Registration_Athlete table:
---------------------------
Registration_ID (Foreign Key to REGISTRATION)
People_ID      (Foreign Key to PEOPLE)
```

I am not a mysql person, but I would think this simple type of structure would work.

Finally, storing credit card information is problematic as it runs into PCI (Payment Card Institute) rules, which you will want to avoid (think complicated and expensive).  Consider processing payments through a third party, such as Google Checkout, etc. and not capturing the credit card.

Comment: I will not retain the names for future submission. Once a submission is complete - any returning athlete or manager is like new to me. At the end of registration, i need to pass off ALL information to another group in CSV format so having multiple tables doesn't seem right to me. Thoughts?

Also - I am not going to be storing CC information based on PCI compliance.

Comment: @JM4 - Even if your system just collects the credit card and only passes it along (no storing), you have now entered the PCI world.  Sorry about that.  Regarding multiple tables, either the user or your program will have to duplicate the constant information in the table.  Unless you want to go with one text field and put everything in an XML document or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Well based on your comment reply and what you are looking for. You could do this.

---

Create one database for Registration.

Create the columns ID, name, regDate, isManager, ManagerID (Whatever Else you need).

When a Manager enrolls set isManager to 1 and form a hash based on name and regdate, that would be the Managers Unique ID that would be added to all of the Athletes entries that the manager registers.

When a lone athlete registers don't worry about the ID and just set isManager to 0.

---

I think I may be oversimplifying it though. Wouldn't be the greatest for forming different types of queries but it should be alright if you are trying to minimize your db footprint

Comment: I really don't think I will ever do a DB query on this. I am only storing the information just for reference in the event of meltdown. The registration needs to capture the athlete information and pass it to the medical practice. The only reason we capture manager is to know who is paying. Athlete solo or 100 athletes, all information is passed along. Doing it this way though means I have to create over 400 fields within the table which is a huge pain and will take a very long time. Looking for solution on how to associate athletes with a manager yet pass them along in a single row